# триггеры: обновить несколько строк которые выбираются из другой таблицы по ID строки из таблицы запускающей триггер

Tags: mysql, триггер

Имеется триггер, который при обновлении данных, а точнее при блокировании видео (`status = 0`) корректирует количество видео по каждому из тегов. При этом для одного видео имеется несколько тегов, соответственно требуется уменьшить количество видео по всем тегам, которые "прикреплены" к блокируемому видео. За это отвечает запрос: `SELECT tag_id FROM videotags WHERE video_id = id` (выбрать `tag_id`, где `video_id` = ID  из обновляемой строки таблицы `videos`), не уверен, что все делаю точно, так как обновление срабатывает только для одного тега, хотя их в базе 2.

```
таблица videos
id          status — ID видео и статус видео
1           1

таблица tags
id          videos_count — ID тега и кол-во видео для каждого тега
1           1
2           1

таблица videotags
tag_id      video_id — ID тега и ID видео для которого выбраны теги
1           1
2           1

CREATE TRIGGER `videos_count` AFTER UPDATE ON `videos`
FOR EACH ROW UPDATE tags
SET videos_count = IF(NEW.status = 0, videos_count - 1, videos_count) 
WHERE id IN (SELECT tag_id FROM videotags WHERE video_id = id)
```

Как сделать чтобы триггер обновлял данные для всех тегов (IDs: 1 и 2) которые закреплены за блокируемым видео ID 1?

Comment: А как вы указываете ID блокируемого видео? В запросе есть только `id`. Замените его на `NEW.id`: `SELECT tag_id FROM videotags WHERE video_id = NEW.id`

Comment: Используемый вами подход, с моей точки зрения, не является безопасным. Да, простой декремент счётчика хорошо, но будет ли гарантия актуальности значения при ошибках. Вполне может быть, что значение счётчика и количество активных видео могут начать различаться. Но, в виду того, что я не знаю вашей систему, я не могу утверждать, что так и будет.

Comment: Можете посмотреть пример запроса здесь: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/52bdf/5. Здесь просто выборка для video с id = 1. Как вы можете увидеть, в результате 2 записи. При update эти записи будут обновлены.

Comment: @Vitaly, да с `NEW.id` обрабатывает как надо. Но `id` не обновляется, почему там следует ставить его как NEW.id? ведь обновление затрагивает только `NEW.status`.

Comment: Не зависит от того, обновляется поле или нет - просто "новый" набор полей. Нужно воспринимать как поля из обновляемых записей (строк).